# Why the object isn't adding the other elements that also share the same first character?

Tags: javascript, object

```
function groupBy(array) { 

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var firstChar = array[i][0]
  result[firstChar] = [];
  
  if (array[i].indexOf(firstChar) > -1) {      
  result[firstChar].push(array[i])
 }
}
return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(['apple', 'cat', 'boat', 'card', 'bond']));
```

This is what I expected to get: { 'a': ['apple'], 'c': ['cat', 'card'], 'b': ['boat', 'bond'] }.

However, I'm only able to add one of the words to the array ({ 'a': ['apple'], 'c': ['card'], 'b': ['bond'] }). Could someone explain why my code is doing that? and also why is it skipping the first word that it encounters (i.e. "cat", "boat")? Anything would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `result[firstChar] = [];` overwrites the object property with a new, empty array on each iteration

Comment: That `if` statement doesn't make sense. `array[i].indexOf(firstChar)` is always `0`. (Ok, unless  `array[i]` is the empty string)

Answer (score 0):

You are re-writing the array. first check if the value of `result[firstChar]` is undefined, if it's undefined then only initialize it with an empty array.

```js
function groupBy(array) {
  var result = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var firstChar = array[i][0];
    if (!result[firstChar]) {
      result[firstChar] = [];
    }
    if (array[i].indexOf(firstChar) > -1) {
      result[firstChar].push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(['apple', 'cat', 'boat', 'card', 'bond']));
```